# JavaScript code not executing in dialog window

Tags: javascript

I'm at a loss as to why my JavaScript code is not executing in a dialog window.
I'm using the following code to monitor when the DOM element that I want the code to be applied to has been loaded:

```
let ready = function () {

  // If the body element and the element exist
  if (document.querySelector('#TxtEmailBody')) {

    let id = document.querySelector('#TxtEmailBody');
    let pasteText = document.createTextNode("Test");
    id.appendChild(pasteText);

    // Return so that we don't call requestAnimationFrame() again
    return;
  }

  // If the body element isn't found, run ready() again at the next pain
  window.requestAnimationFrame(ready);
};

// Initialize our ready() function
window.requestAnimationFrame(ready);
```

To my understanding, this code should monitor the DOM until `#TxtEmailBody` has been loaded an change the text within that element. However, it's not executing.

I suppose it is because the DOM elements of the dialog window have not been loaded when the actual code executes. But that's what the `ready()` function is supposed to monitor for.

Playing with the Chrome Dev Tools console I was not able to get the element by Id  or `querySelector` unless unless I first loaded the dialog window, then (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) selected an element to focus the developer tools window on this dialog.

I checked and the dialog is not an `iframe` which would explain why the code is not executed in the dialog window.

Edit: Here's the markup for the  in which the element to act on exists in:

```
<div class="ms-core-form-line">
<textarea name="TxtEmailBody" rows="6" cols="40" id="TxtEmailBody" onkeyup="OnEmailBodyKeyUp(this)"
    alwaysenablesilent="true" onpaste="MultiLineTextBoxOnPaste(this, 2000)" class="ms-helperText ms-fullWidth ms-aclinv-message-input"
    onblur="OnEmailBodyBlur(this)" oninput="OnEmailBodyInput(this)" onfocus="OnEmailBodyFocus(this)" onkeypress="MultiLineTextBoxOnKeyPress(this, 2000)"
    title="E-mail body text field"></textarea>
<div id="emailBodyCounter" class="ms-aclinv-emailBodyCounter"></div>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `document.querySelector('#someId')` instead of `document.getElementById('someId')`? `getElementById` is significantly faster.

Comment: what happen in chrome console when you put `console.log('x')` on free space below first line?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm a beginner and didn't know about the performance difference but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: This seems to run fine. 'x' is printed in the first line and 'undefined' in the second line below that.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo this means that is something wrog - 'x' shoud be printed a looooot of times (ont only 2) - however put another `console.log('y')` inside `if` in `ready()` function and debug in that way

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski: You're right. I hadn't put `console.log('x')`in the function before. Now this works as expected. It's looping constantly. Next,I put `console.log('y')`into the if statement. Unfortunately, it never evaluates to true, x is still constantly printed. Could it be that the dialog window is executed in a whole other DOM or scope or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo - yes this is possible - you can debug it a little - put inside ready() function follwing code `console.log(document)` and inspect doom tree wchih appear in console AFTER dialog appear

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, if the element with id #TxtEmailBody is an input it will not get the value of the node pasteText.

Structure of a input is

```
<input type="text" id="TxtEmailBody" value="My Input" />
```

and after applying `id.appendChild(pasteText)` 
it will become

```
  <input type="text" id="TxtEmailBody" value="My Input">Test</input>
```

and the value will still be `"My Input"`

If this is the case, then you can set the value

```
id.value = pasteText.nodeValue;
```

Comment: The element's id #TxtEmailBody exists within a <div>. I added the code to the original post. I does not respond in the chron dev console unless I  (Ctrl+Shift+C) select an element on the dialog window. simply opening the chrome dev console from the parent site does not register input on the dialog window. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<textarea ... id="#TxtEmailBody" ... >
```

to

```
<textarea ... id="TxtEmailBody" ... >
```

in other words: remove hash from `id` (because `document.querySelector('#TxtEmailBody')` try to find element in html which have `id="TxtEmailBody"` (hash is symbol of `id` in query selector) )! Also remember rule that **id attribute must be unique for whole html document**.

Comment: My  bad. `<textarea ... id="TxtEmailBody" ... >` originally had no hash in it. When I added this code to my original post I pasted it with the hash because the id in that original code was actually 'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_txtEmailBody' and not 'TxtEmailBody'. I just used '#TxtEmailBody' for better readability in my post. I corrected the mistake in the code in the original post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong to begin with, let me explain. I load the page, hit F12, select any element with Ctrl+Shift+C. back on the page, I click the button that opens the dialog window. I switch back to Chrome dev console and run `document.querySelector('#TxtEmailBody');`. Nothing is found. But when I use Ctrl+Shift+C again on any element of the dialog window and repeat `document.querySelector('#TxtEmailBody');` it will find it. It must have something to do with the dialog window being loaded in another DOM context if that makes sense.

Comment: WHen you put console.log('x') in first line of `ready()` function you should see a lot of 'x' on console - thath 'x' chould be printed all time (never stops until querySelector find TxtEmailBody). - It is true?